# NPM error can't find present "es2015" - babel/node/react

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm, babeljs

I'm getting the following NPM error when I deploy to Heroku. My project is a [mern stack](http://mern.io/).

**Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/app"**

[image]

Packages seem to be installed correctly, I have a .babelrc file set up correctly, and nothing is different locally compared to remote other than the parent directories are different. On Heroku, the parent directory is obviously "app". These are my NPM packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "css-modules-require-hook": "^4.0.0",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.1",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
    "css-modules-require-hook": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  }
```

Furthermore, `npm start` runs **index.js** which consists of the following:

```
require('babel-core/register');
require('babel-polyfill');
require('css-modules-require-hook');
require('./server/index');
```

I actually was getting errors with `babel-polyfill` and `css-modules-require-hook` not being found or something (I can't remember unfortunately) but when I added them from my devDependencies to my dependencies, it seemed to resolve itself. It's rather difficult to determine what packages to put where actually (any tips?). I'd really appreciate some direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what i understand, heroku defaults to adding the --production flag, which inturn doesnt install your devdependencies. I'd move all necessary dependencies to create your build to devDep to dependencies.
or

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

Comment: dude, you're 100% correct. When I add all my devDependencies to dependencies it works. However, isn't this bad practice? How can I distinguish between what should or should not be a dependency in production? Thanks for your help!

Comment: simply put dependencies are needed to run the application, devDependencies are only needed to develop the application. In your case, heroku needs some devDependencies to build the application before it runs, therefore you have to do that. but you could still omit devDependencies that arent used to create a build, like dependencies for testing for example karma, protractor,linting etc